# What purpose do these capacitors have?

Tags: mosfet, power-amplifier, common-source

[image: Common Source Amplifier]

What is the purpose of Cc1,Cc2 and Cs and what is the normal range of these capacitors? Also what is Negative Feed Back(Rs) mean I can't understand it.

Comment: Rs is what's called "local NFB" to suggest that it operates *within* the stage and not between stages. It has several different meanings in this context -- both temperature NFB as well as signal NFB. Can you analyze this circuit both with respect to small signal variation as well as thermal/temperature variations?

Answer (score 1):

CC1 and CC2 are to provide AC-coupled signals to the input and output. This prevents the DC voltage on the input (perhaps 0 V) from upsetting the bias on the transistor.

10 uF would be a typical value, but this depends on the low frequency cutoff you want.

CS bypasses RS at high frequencies. This raises the gain from approximately -RD/(RS+gm) to -RD/gm. gm depends inversely on the bias current of the transistor.

Comment: A bit hard to see but it's CS  (not C3), better to see if you enlarge the picture a bit.